# Given coordinates of 3 lights, how can I find out the angles between the camera and the lights?

Tags: math, trigonometry, triangulation

I bought this:

[image]

And I want to write software to use it as a lightgun for PC by obtaining the coordinates of the lights via a webcam. That's the easy part.

But what's the math required to find where it's aiming given the light's coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

By coordinates you mean, probably usual cartesian coordinates (x, y, z). To find out angles between object located at those coordinates and some reference panes (for example, horizon and some "vertical" pane showing zero direction) you can transform cartesian coordinaes into sperical polar ones. Refer, for example, to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system.

Comment: That went way over my head. Any chance you could simplify the formulas? Also, I don't have the Z, just X,Y

Comment: There are clear formulas at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates. Or, if I didn't understand your question completely, please ask more precisely.

Comment: Those forumlas need Z, I only have X/Y of 3 the three lights (obtained by 2d web camera) shown in the picture

Comment: OK, this is quite clear now. I think you can find an angle easily by arctg(y/x). And no matter which is distance to the target.

Comment: How would that tell me where it's pointing? That formula only uses 1 point. I have the trig formulas for find angles between 2 X/Y coordinates, do you mean I use the angles between the lights somehow?

Comment: Oh, my prev. comment is completely wrong, sorry. If you don't know the distanse to the target, you need to consider not targets, but their projection on the focal plane of your camera instead. Imagine the right triangle with x, y cathetuses. You can find the hypothenuse h=sqrt(x^2 + y^2). Next, distance to the focal pane (f) is a projection to it, so it's prependicular to h. You have another right triangle with h and f cathetuses, and you need the angle opposite h. It is equal to arctan(h/f).

Comment: ...And a little bit to make things more clear :) Focal plane is a matrix; f (perpendicular to focal plane) is a focal length written on camera lens. x and y I used in formula above are not coordinates you received, but distances from matrix center to projection of target. To find it for X, use x = (X - ResX/2) / ResX * SizeX, where X is coordinate you've got, ResX is horizontal resolution of the matrix (maximal X coordinate), SizeX is horizontal size of matrix, must be specified in manual. So this should be enough, good luck :)